# Is passing record to SQL Server from external application equally expensive than passing it within the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-types, table-valued-parameters

So I have a stored procedure in which I pass user defined table type parameter from my C# web application.

I pass thousands of them.

Now within the stored procedure I modify this data a bit and so I pass that data to another table valued function. So basically, it is this kind of stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PortalUI.GetActiveAlertCategoryStatistic
     @assetRelationCollection StringCollection READONLY
    ,@excludedAlertCodes      StringCollection READONLY
    ,@siteId                  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #TempAssetRelation FROM fn_getSiteAssetIdsForAlertFetching(@assetRelationCollection,@siteId)

    -- Further code
END
```

So you can see I am accepting `@assetRelationCollection` a user defined table type in the procedure, which can have thousands of rows.

Then I am again passing it to the function to add one more row.

So my question is that is passing that `@assetRelationCollection` from my C# application to SQL Server is equally expensive than passing it to the table valued function within the SQL Server?

And second is it at all expensive to pass data from one procedure to a function within the SQL Server?

Comment: Passing from C# to SQL Server requires external, potentially network resources (you don't say if the C# code is running on the same server or not). I'm fairly sure either way that the call from C# will be significantly slower than the function call within SQL Server.

Comment: @DaleK - Yes, that I also assume that it must be slower. But do you know if it at all takes any performance while passing data to the function from the stored procedure?

Comment: Everything SQL Server does takes memory and CPU... thats its job... do you have an alternative you want to compare it to? If so go ahead and measure the performance.